# How to zip a script-file for MacOS under Windows and give it correct attributes?

Tags: bash, script, zip, extended-attributes

I am working under Windows 10 and am putting together a few data-files and a simple bash-script that I want to share with Mac-Users. (I am just learning MacOS, so may have drawn wrong conclusions somewhere...)

When I tried to use that stuff on a Mac, the script would not execute after unzipping and I needed to set its attributes to allow execution.
Is it possible to do that already under windows so that the file unzips with desired attributes set?

Comment: I haven't used Windows in too many years; however, I understand there is a Windows Subsystem for Linux available. Is this what you're using for your `bash` _scripts_? If yes, how are you zipping the _script(s)_, via command line or GUI?  If by the GUI, I'd try running a command line version of `zip` for Linux to see if it will retain the executable attribute.

Comment: No no, I'm working on "pure Windows" and have just written the script with a text-editor. It's not supposed to be used unser Windows, it's just borne there because that happens to be my development-environment. But while the script ise useless under window, I want unzipping user to be able to use it immediately,

Comment: I'm talking about a Windows 10 feature: Have a look at [Everything You Can Do With Windows 10’s New Bash Shell](https://www.howtogeek.com/265900/everything-you-can-do-with-windows-10s-new-bash-shell/) and [https://www.howtogeek.com/265900/everything-you-can-do-with-windows-10s-new-bash-shell/](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/). If doing it by the command line using a Linux `zip` under the Windows Subsystem for Linux. Another suggestion is to run Linux via Virtual Machine and do it there.

Comment: A zipped `bash` executable from a Linux Virtual Machine will be executable on macOS when unzipped.

Comment: Oh sorry, I hadn't realised that. That sounds promising indeed. Feel free to post that as a reply, than I accept it and close the question :)

Comment: MBaas, I did as you asked and posted as an answer, however, if you not going to accept it (and maybe upvote it too) then I'm going to delete it as one user, whose obviously not capable of understanding it, chose to down vote it in spite of you finding it acceptable in your comment to me asking to post it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry - I was not intending to let you go unrewarded - was just hoping there might be a more convenient answer...

Comment: Well if something else gets added feel free to accept it if you find it a better answer for you, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Windows in to many years; however, I understand there is a new Windows 10 feature called Windows Subsystem for Linux. Have a look at [Everything You Can Do With Windows 10’s New Bash Shell](https://www.howtogeek.com/265900/everything-you-can-do-with-windows-10s-new-bash-shell/) and [How to Install and Use the Linux Bash Shell on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/). Maybe using this feature will enable one to create and zip a `bash` executable and retain its attributes once unzipped on a Mac. I haven't tested it, so this is more informational then a working answer.

There are quite a few steps in the two linked articles and so as not to make this a so called link only answer, since I'm not quoting any of the steps, let me tell you something you can do from Windows that will work for sure...

Install Linux in a Virtual Machine and do your scripting, make it executable, and zip it up in the Linux VM. A zipped `bash` executable from a Linux Virtual Machine will be executable on macOS when unzipped.

Comment: -1.  First you propose an answer "I haven't tested it" and then as a second attempt propose setting the flags in Linux VM when the question was how to do it in Windows.  If you are adding your flags in a different OS you may as well do it in macOS.